# How do I avoid eval in elisp?

Tags: lisp, elisp

I have wrote a simple util to submit my code to [a online judge site](http://poj.org), how to avoid the evil function?

```
(setq url-proxy-services '(("http" . "localhost:8888")))
(setq debug-on-error t)

(require-package 'http-post-simple) 
(require 'http-post-simple)
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))

(defstruct form action (method "POST") fields)

(defstruct site url forms)

(setq poj (make-site :url "http://poj.org" :forms '(
                            (login .
                               (make-form 
                                :action "login"
                                :fields `(
                                      (user_id1 . "you-name")
                                      (password1 . ,(read-passwd "input your password: "))
                                      (url . "%2F")
                                      (B1 . "login"))))
                            (submit .
                                (make-form
                                 :action "submit"
                                 :fields `(
                                       (problem_id ,(read-string "inpur problem id: "))
                                       (language ,(read-string "select language: 0:G++,1:GCC,2:Java,3:Pascal,4:C++,5:C,6:Fortan "))
                                       (source ,(with-temp-buffer
                                          (insert-file-contents (read-file-name "select source file"))(buffer-string)))
                                       (submit "Submit"))))
                            (logout .
                                (make-form
                                 :action "login?action=logout&url=%2F"
                                 :method "GET")))))



(defun http-get-simple(url)
          (let (header data status)
            (with-current-buffer 
            (url-retrieve-synchronously url)
              (setq status url-http-response-status)
              (goto-char (point-min))
              (if (search-forward-regexp "^$" nil t)
              (setq header (buffer-substring (point-min) (point))
                data   (buffer-substring (1+ (point)) (point-max)))
            (setq data (buffer-string)))
              (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
              (values data header status)))


(defun request-site(site form)
  "perform a request to site"
  (let* ((url (site-url site))
     (form (cdr (assoc form (site-forms site))))
     (form-inst (eval form))
     (result (if (equal (form-method form-inst) "POST")
             (http-post-simple (concat url "/" (form-action form-inst))
                       (form-fields form-inst))
           (http-get-simple (concat url "/" (form-action form-inst))))))
    result))


(defun poj-login()
  (interactive)
  (request-site poj 'login))

(defun poj-logout()
  (interactive)
  (request-site poj 'logout))


(defun poj-submit()
  (interactive)
  (request-site poj 'submit))
```

Above is my code, I have tried this

```
(let* ((form (cdr (assoc 'submit (site-forms poj))))
       (frm-inst (apply (car form) (cdr form)))) ; get weird result
  (eval form)) ; get proper result
```

And can you give me some advice about coding style?

Comment: please indent your code properly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that *forms* are *evaluated* while *functions* are *called* (using `funcall` or `apply`).

I.e., the way you structure your code (lists of forms) you are painting yourself into the `eval` corner.  You need to replace lists of forms with lists of functions and then you will be able to use `funcall` or `apply`.

E.g., replace

```
`((problem_id ,(read-string "inpur problem id: "))
  (language ,(read-string "select language: 0:G++,1:GCC,2:Java,3:Pascal,4:C++,5:C,6:Fortan "))
  (source ,(with-temp-buffer
            (insert-file-contents (read-file-name "select source file"))
            (buffer-string)))
  (submit "Submit"))
```

with something like

```
`((problem-id read-string "problem id: ")
  (language read-string "language: 0:G++,1:GCC,2:Java,3:Pascal,4:C++,5:C,6:Fortan ")
  (source ,(lambda () (file-to-string (read-file-name "source file: "))))
  (submit identity "Submit"))
```

Where `file-to-string` is defined thus:

```
(defun file-to-string (file)
  "Read the content of FILE and return it as a string."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (buffer-string)))
```

Now you can replace `(eval form)` with `(apply (car form) (cdr form))`.

Comment: Use lambda can't get right result, because `cl-defstruct` will wrap list with list, it's so weird. Thanks for your answer, it a good clue.

Comment: @ifree: you should use defstruct-defined accessors instead of car/cdr.